# Can't get automapper-ts working in an angular 2+ project

Tags: angular, automapper

I've followed the following post to install and configure automapper-ts:
https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper/issues/17

then added the following in the component constructor:

```
    automapper.createMap(MyUserDto, UserDto);
```

then tried to use the map function as follows:

```
        let moduser = automapper.map(MyUserDto, UserDto, user);
```

but moduser is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure you're using automapper correctly?  Looks like you need to specify the properties to map, and from the samples it uses strings when creating a map.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I used this approach:
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/39452054/asp-net-core-with-ef-core---dto-collection-mapping